# jQuery - define variable and run function for an element that loses certain class

Tags: jquery, removeclass, eventtrigger, flexslider

I know there are some similar questions here but I am trying to get a specific value.

I am working on Flexslider http://www.woothemes.com/FlexSlider/ and trying to add some special functions to the slide that loses the "flex-active-slide" class. Based on the documentation, I have managed to insert my function before and after the slide animation.

```
// Callback API
start: function(){},
before: function(){ 
  $('li.image').someFunction(); //this is where I need to trigger this event only to the li.image that's losing the flex-active-slide class
},                          
after: function() {
  $('li.flex-active-slide').otherFunction(); //this is where the active class
},
```

I don't need to run the function for all the other `li.image` elements as you see in the example above, only for the one that looses the flex-active-slide class.

I would need to get this element and define it with a variable so I can correctly run the function only for the `li.image`, this also makes sense for performance optimization purposes.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is to edit your plugin file itself

open `jquery.flexslider.js`

find the following code

```
 active: function() {
          slider.controlNav.removeClass(namespace + "active").eq(slider.animatingTo).addClass(namespace + "active");
        }
```

You can use `slider.controlNav` in this function for your work. `slider.controlNav` refers to the `li` element you find its child image using jQuery's `.find`

If it does not works you can find `active-slide` in this file and see wherever this class is removed, you can add your code in those places

**UPDATE**: the $('li.image').eq(slider.currentSlide) is the way to call the slide that loses the active class.

Comment: I know this has to do with that but I don't understand how I can call that specific li right after it loses the active class.

Comment: in this active function the `slider.controlNav` refers to the `li` in other places `slider.currentSlide` refers to the `li`. You can write write `var myLi= slider.currentSlide; //remove class code` then `myLi.your code` roughly I can say `myLi` will be shortcut for `$('li.flex-active-slide')` after class removal

Comment: $('li.image').eq(slider.currentSlide) this is how to get that slide, thanks so much. Your answer is best. I edited your answer to make easy for code seekers :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something like this...

```
var somevar;

start: function(){},
before: function() {
    somevar = $('li.image.flex-active-slide');
},
after: function() {
    $.each(somevar, function( index, elem ) {
        if( !$(elem).hasClass('flex-active-slide')) ) {
            // Obviously it has lost the flex-active-slide class.
        }
    });
}
```

I doubt it is easily possible to determine before the plugin has actually done something whether an element is losing the said class without modifying the plugin itself. Therefore even the `.someFunction()` method you have there must be executed in the `after` callback.